# Кельн чи Кьольн? (німецьке місто)

Tags: власні-назви, from-german

Вікіпедія пропонує [Кельн](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD), але оскільки німецькою правильно [Кьольн (Köln)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Koeln), то у мене закрався сумнів, а чи не є написання через "е" (Кельн) калькою з російської Кёльн/Кельн. Якщо українською правильно все таки через "е", то цікаво, чому саме так, а не інакше, і який шлях пройшло слово від оригінальної назви Кьольн (Köln) до Кельн.

Comment: Правопис ґрунтується на думці, що [œ], [ø:] ближчі до нашого "е", оскільки є огубленим [е]. Проте за такою логікою треба писати "Мінхен" замість Мюнхен, бо ж [ʏ] відсутнє в українській мові і є фактично огубленим [i]. Але вже що є.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Написання іншомовних назв українською не завжди точно відтворює оригінальне звучання (навіть серед можливих з точки зору української абетки та фонології варіантів часто обирається не найближчий). Частково — традиції, частково — тому що часто простіше транслітерувати, а не транскрибувати звучання.

1. [Український правопис 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par91):

   > #### § 91. *E*, *Ö*, *EU*
   >
   > 1. *Е* передається літерою *е*: екватор, екзаменатор, електрика, енергія, ентузіазм, етап, ідеал, каре, силует, театр, фаетон, філе; Еквадор, Па-де-Кале, Теруель; Есхіл.

   Чому вони внесли німецьке *ö* в категорію букв і буквосполук, що звучать як *е*/*є*, мені невідомо але далі в примітці вони висловлюються ще конкретніше:

   > *Oe*, *ö*, *eu* передаються літерою *е*: […].

   І серед прикладів навіть безпосередньо:

   > ***Кельн***
2. [Інструкція з передачі українською мовою німецьких географічних назв і термінів (2001)](http://www.ukrmap.com.ua/u/1/files/Deutschland.zip) на [сторінці ДНВП «Картографія»](http://ukrmap.com.ua/services/kodeksi-ustalenoji-praktiki/):

   > ```
   > +–––+––––––––––+–––––––––––+––––––––––––––––+–––––––––+
   > | № | Німецька | Передача  |    Приклади    |Примітки |
   > |з/п|літера або|українською|                |         |
   > |   |буквоспо- |   мовою   |                |         |
   > |   | лучення  |           |                |         |
   > +–––+––––––––––+–––––––––––+––––––––––––––––+–––––––––+
   > |                         […]                         |
   > +–––+––––––––––+–––––––––––+––––––––––––––––+–––––––––+
   > | 8.|ö, öh     |е          |Örtze – Ерце    |         |
   > |   |          |           |Döbern – Деберн |         |
   > |   |          |           |Öhna – Ена      |         |
   > |   |          |           |Löhme – Леме    |         |
   > |   +----------+-----------+----------------+---------+
   > | 8.|oe        |е          |Oederan – Едеран|[œ], [ø:]|
   > |   |          |           |Moers – Мерс    |         |
   > +–––+––––––––––+–––––––––––+––––––––––––––––+–––––––––+
   > ```

   Тобто теж ***Кельн***, як би воно не писалося: *Köln* чи навіть *Koeln*.

   Це підтверджує і [їхній газетир (покажчик) для Європи](http://www.ukrmap.com.ua/u/1/files/EUROPE.pdf).
3. [Рекомендації щодо транслітерування літерами української абетки власних назв, поданих німецькою мовою](http://sdip.gov.ua/t/docman/binary/trans/06ND43.doc) на [сторінці Державної служби інтелектуальної власності України](http://sips.gov.ua/ua/transliteruvannja.html) рекомендує спочатку записати транскрипцію (транскрипційними знаками англійської мови), яка виглядатиме як *kœln*, а далі, відповідно:

   > ```
   > +–––––+–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+–––––––––––––––––+
   > |№ п/п|Транскрипційні знаки англійської мови|Українські літери|
   > +–––––+–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+–––––––––––––––––+
   > |                             […]                             |
   > +–––––+–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+–––––––––––––––––+
   > | 10  |                  œ                  |        е        |
   > +–––––+–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+–––––––––––––––––+
   > ```

   Тобто теж ***Кельн***.

<sub>До речі, рекомендації правопису не завжди збігаються з рекомендаціями Укркартографії. Іноді Укркартографія пропонує щось зовсім неоковирне з точки зору правопису і здорового глузду, типу *Браз**і**лія*, а іноді, навпаки, передає точніше. Але в даному випадку рекомендації всіх трьох збігаються.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Так сталося бо [умляут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut) ö

У [цій статті](http://www.thegermanprofessor.com/how-to-pronounce-o-and-u/) наводяться наступні відомості:

> *To pronounce the ö-sound, say “ay” as in day (or as in the German word See). While continuing to make this sound, tightly round your lips. Look in a mirror to make sure your lips are actually rounded. Voilà! The resulting sound is the ö-sound.*

Тож ні українське `е`, ні українське `ьо` не зможуть точно передати звук.

Також зверніть увагу, що німецьке `ö` [іноді записується діграфом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography#Umlaut_diacritic_usage) `oe`, який читається так само як наведено вище. Також у братній до німецької нідерландській мові відсутній умляут `ö`, але присутній діграф `oe`, [який взагалі перетворився на `[u]`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Dutch/Alfabet#The_oe)

Тобто здавалось правильно було б перевести латинику в кирилицю як `Коельн`

Але за [цим посиланням](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ln) наведено приклад вимови `Köln`, який можна розібрати як кх[<sub>eу</sub>?<sup>oу</sup>]йн.

Comment: Диграф `oe` у нідерланській не "перетворився на `[u]`", він здавна послідовно використовувася для записування саме цього звука. Німецьке `ö` по суті не має абсолютно ніякого стосунку до нідердандського `oe`.